# Running the same node.js app twice at the same time

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, pm2

I have a express node app listening on port `4000` on a `nginx` server using `pm2`, a react front end using `axios` sends a csv file, then the node app makes an API request and process it for about 5 minutes, finally it sends the response.

The request itself runs concurrently with a promise on a loop and as data comes along it appends using `fs` to a file, when all is done about 5 minutes later it takes that file and process it further, then it sends the response.

My question is, how can I make it so, while it's processing the first request, another user runs the same node app?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: To be very clear. What takes 5 minutes? Does the app make an API request, waits 5 minutes for the result, then sends the response or does the app make an API request, waits zero seconds and gets the results immediately then spends another 5 minutes in a very long for loop processing the results then send the response?

Comment: It takes 5 minutes to process, the API request runs in parallel and I am appending as the data comes along with fs

Comment: So the API takes 5 minutes to complete? Then there is nothing else you need to do. Another user can easily make a request to your app while the first request is completing

Comment: @slebetman Even thou while the API is completing and I am taking the response and storing each result  in an obj, then appending and clearing that obj, in a loop till the request ends ?

Comment: When you say in a loop do you mean a for or while loop with async/await?

Comment: I am using a async await map promise on each keyword request and then foreach with the response, all this on node

Comment: Then the only thing that blocks is the foreach with the response. Awaiting the promises does not block the process. Yes, it looks like there is nothing you need to do. Node already handles what you want